# How to make webpage based authorisation for Java webstart application?

Tags: java, authorization, java-web-start

I try to find some solution for such case: user authorises on site. After this he can start WebStart application. Application should know who executed it and be sure that user who executed it is authorised.
I know that I can path paramters to webstart application with help of JNLP config file, but:

- in this case I should generate one new config per user
- I can't be sure that someone else (not authorised user) won't be able to execute app

So, how I can implement such behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will evetually have to solve this problem my self. What ive been thinking so far.. When user clicks the jnlp link, a servlet could atleast make sure the user is logged in before it allows download of the generated jnlp. The parameter (temporary token) passed to the application would then only be accepted by webservice if httpsession is still active.

Comment: So ive tried my own idea. Problem is the jnlp get served a total of 4 times before my jws-app is started and only the first time is in the same session as the user has on the webpage.